# UITableViewCell selection flickers on reload

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which I have hooked up to a `NSFetchedResultsController`. When an object is updated, I use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` to reload the cell.  I want to keep the cell selected while it is reloaded. The below code is how I am reselecting the cell after the update.  It works, but the cell displays unselected for about half a second before becoming selected again and looks bad. `self.selectedIndexPath` is set in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

I've also tried setting the cell to selected and highlighted in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but that did nothing.

Does anyone know how to prevent the flickering? I'm using iOS 8.3 BTW.

```
// Called in controllerWillChangeContent
[self.tableView beginUpdates];

...

// Called in didChangeObject
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

...

// Called in controllerDidChangeContent
[self.tableView endUpdates];

if( self.selectedIndexPath ) {
        [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:self.selectedIndexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```

Comment: This might be kind of contrived, but maybe after you call reloadRowsAtIndexPaths you can call cellForRowAtIndexPath with the same index, if that index is equal to self.selectedIndexPath you can then set its background color to the selected color. If that works you just need to be sure to reset the background color in cell for row at index path if it isn't selected.

Comment: I can't call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` directly, as that would generate a new cell which would not be used by the `UITableView`.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. If you call [self.tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath: ] it "Returns the table cell at the specified index path." and it "returns nil if cell is not visible or index path is out of range." It shouldn't make a new cell, it should return the one it's already using. It's different than the data source method - tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Oh I see, you're correct.

Comment: I ended up removing the call to `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` and fetched the cell from the tableview and reconfigured it myself. This works around the problem, but I'd be curious to know if there is a solution to the flickering.